# While loop command and stdout processing

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a Bash function, `foo()`, which will return 0 or 1 always. When it is returning 0, it would have produced some stdout:

```
foo() {
    if ...
      echo "aaa\nbbb"
      return 0
    else
      return 1
    fi
}
```

I want to repeatedly call this `foo` function, process its stdout, until it returns non-zero:

```
while foo; do
  # process foo's stdout that that one execution
done
```

But I don't know how to cleanly store the stdout of `foo` and use it in the while expression at the same time.

In ruby I might have done something like:

```
while text = self.foo do
  ...
end
```

Any suggestions? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one explained why your code doesnt work.

1. Dont mix `echo` and `return`, use `print(f)` in combination with `return` instead. This will seperate function-stdout from function-signals.
2. I would not recomment using a function to initiate a loop, because this way the function and loop will get called once only. You can run a infinity loop and break it when the requerments are met instead.

The code could look like this ...

```
#!/bin/bash

function foo() {
    if [ true = true ]; then    # some simple test
        printf "aaa\nbbb"   # stdout
        return 0    # singal (function status)
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

while true  # infinity loop
do
    STDOUT=$(foo)   
    ERRNO="$?"  # error number / return value / signal
    if [ "$ERRNO" -ne 0 ] ; then # -ne means Not Equal
        break   # end loop
    fi
    echo "$STDOUT"
done

exit "$ERRNO"   # exit with return value of foo
```

The output will look like this ...

```
aaa
bbb
aaa
bbb
```

till you hit `ctrl-c` or the function return is `1`.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean by "This will seperate function-stdout from function-signals"? Do you mean like, use `echo` only when one only wanting to print completely irrelevant text, but use `printf` to denote printing functional text, due to the fact that `echo` only returns 0 but `printf` can return non-0?

Comment: What I meant is `echo` may work in some cases, but when formating a text `echo` can remove backslashes and other symbols while using posix. `printf` on the other hand will always format a text like you want.

Comment: combine `printf` with `return` to make the function more solid.

Answer (score 1):

I would change a bit the `while` like:

```
foo() {
    if (( $RANDOM % 5 ))
    then
        seq $(( $RANDOM % 10 ))
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

while :
do
    #store the output to variable and check the return value
    var="$(foo)" || { echo no more input; exit 1; }
    echo got $(grep -c . <<<"$var") lines
done
```

it prints like:

```
got 9 lines
got 6 lines
got 4 lines
got 8 lines
got 2 lines
got 2 lines
no more input
```

Answer (score 1):

A `while` can test a command, like the `true` or the `false` command:

```
 while false; do echo true ; done
```

...which outputs nothing.  A `while` also acts the same way if the command is an assignment:

```
 while x=$(false) ; do echo true ; done
```

In the above code, the loop won't run, and `$x` is empty.  Change it to `x=$(true)` and it runs `echo true` forever.

So it's like the `ruby` code:

```
while text = self.foo do
```

...except the syntax is:

```
while text=$(foo); do
```

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious is to save it to a file:

```
foo() {
    if ...
      echo "aaa\nbbb"
      return 0
    else
      return 1
    fi
}

while foo > tmpfile; do
  # process tmpfile
done
rm tmpfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an infinite loop and break when `foo()` returns `1`:

```
while : ; do
    out=$(func)
    [[ $? -eq 1 ]] && break
    # process the stdout of foo() here - which is stored in variable 'out'
    echo $out
done
```

Comment: `echo "$out"` looks better.